# Custom Led / Oled Screens

Tags: display

I have a project where I am in need of a custom shaped display. Where can I as a consumer purchase O-LED or LED screens in a custom shape and dimension such as a half ellipse or ellipse?

And if I have questions like this in the feature where would be the best place to ask such questions?

Comment: Ultimately, you'll get them custom made in China. Go to some trade shows. Don't expect it to be an easy search unless you can bury a regular rectangle inside a custom shape case.